# Nesting ng-model semantically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a very large model that I am creating a form for using AngularJS. It's nested over 4 levels deep and the names of the fields on the model are very long. I end up with markup like this.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="something_super_long.another_very_long_thing.hey_lets_add_another.ok_one_more._last_one_seriously"></input>
```

This is pretty annoying. I wish that I could set up some kind of nested inheritance to avoid setting super long ng-model names over and over. Here is a fully fleshed out EXAMPLE of what I am talking about. I made the model a REASONABLE level of depth only 3 levels of not so long names.

Instead of doing this.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
     <input type="text" ng-model="building_in_san_francisco.layout_floor_1.room_1" />
     <input type="text" ng-model="building_in_san_francisco.layout_floor_1.room_2" />
     <input type="text" ng-model="building_in_san_francisco.layout_floor_1.room_3" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to do something more like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <div ng-model="building_in_san_francisco">
      <div ng-model="layout_floor_1">
        <input type="text" ng-model="room_1" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="room_2" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="room_3" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know if anything like this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could use ng-init in the templates and nest scopes. This keeps your controller clean and uses the child scopes only in the template:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <div ng-scope ng-init="building = buildings.building_in_san_francisco">
            <div ng-scope ng-init="floor = building.layout_floor_1">
                <input type="text" ng-model="floor.room_1" />
                <input type="text" ng-model="floor.room_2" />
                <input type="text" ng-model="floor.room_3" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', function mainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.buildings = {
        building_in_san_francisco: {
            layout_floor_1: {
                room_1: '1',
                room_2: '2',
                room_3: '3'
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: This looks more like what I am looking for.

Comment: The "ng-scope" directive syntax presented here suggests a very clean means of encapsulating references.  I'm trying to locate documentation for  this without much success.  Is this something other than the directive published at http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-scope by Anders D. Johnson?  That seems to not work when "assigned scope includes objects from the parent scope".

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your controller:

```
$scope.something=building_in_san_francisco.layout_floor_1;
```

And when you call it

```
<input type="text" ng-model="something.room_1" />
```